# How to identify that an image comes from a dot matrix printer

Tags: c, opencv, tesseract

I am using Tesseract for OCR character recognition using the Charles Weld C# wrapper.  I am pre-processing the images with Open CV.

My issue is that I need to pre-process the image differently if it came from a dot matrix printout.  Is there a way, using OpenCV, to tell that the image was scanned from a dot matrix printout?

I have tried blurring the image once and counting the differences using AbsDiff which is the technique I use to detect if an image needs to be despeckled but there is no consitent result that indicates dot matrix.

Comment: Sounds like a Masters level research subject.

Comment: Maybe you could share a sample image please?

Comment: How would you tell? It's a matter of resolution. My inkjet is also a dot printer, and you can see that with a glass. Sometimes people insist on an original document, not a scan, and because the original was printed at perhaps 300 dpi, and the scanner is also 300dpi, there will be interference. Perhaps the low resolution ribbon printer output scans better than the inkjet output.

Answer (score 1):

I had a few thoughts and decided to put them down in **ImageMagick** but you can equally do this sort of thing with **OpenCV** and its `findContours()`.

I used this as an input image:

[image]

If you erode the black areas a little using morphology (or alternatively  dilate the white, it comes to the same thing) each of the dots will become separated from adjacent ones. If you then do a *"Connected Component Analysis"* you will see that the image has an abnormally large number of very small dots which are roughly the same height as width - characteristic of circles or dots.

Here is the code I used in Terminal to run **ImageMagick**:

```
magick  dotmatrix.png -threshold 50% -morphology dilate disk:1 \
       -define connected-components:verbose=true               \
       -connected-components 8 -auto-level result.png
```

The output is this image wherein each detected blob gets a successively brighter shade of white:

[image]

More interesting though is the verbose output, which has one line of output per blob detected in the image. It shows lots of small 2x2, 3x2 and similarly sized dots with an area around 7 pixels, circled in red. I would use this as a base for exploring some more...

[image]